# GAE Flex Price as WebSocket Server

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, websocket, price

I would like to know what is the approximate price of a Goggle App Engine Flex f1-micro instance to use it as a websocker server

For example, I can estimate that during the use of 730 hours per month of an e2-micro instance, I will have an estimated cost of USD 6.11 per month. What would be the cost for a similar insanity in GAE flex? Should I assume it is less than that unless I am working 100% of the time?

Answer (score 1):

F1 is listed as $0.05 per hour per instance. Prices are listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing).

Googling is a valuable skill to learn as a developer! You can learn some advanced tricks [here](https://www.semrush.com/blog/google-search-operators/?kw=&cmp=UK_SRCH_DSA_Blog_Core_BU_EN&label=dsa_pagefeed&Network=g&Device=c&utm_content=515816596001&kwid=dsa-1057183188195&cmpid=11776881484&agpid=113846052945&BU=Core&extid=167346300241&adpos=&gclid=Cj0KCQjwppSEBhCGARIsANIs4p6nI_-LzJOc-9_BKqKGJKk1HlWG3rXDyenTCS8yURRoE7wqE1a9CnMaAid0EALw_wcB).

Comment: thank you @schanq The GAE Flex instance shuts down after a request so the monthly cost would be less than Google Compute Engine?

Comment: Per the docs directly under the link I shared: Accrual of instance hours begins when an instance starts and ends as described below, depending on the type of scaling you specify for the instance: • Basic or automatic scaling: accrual ends fifteen minutes after an instance finishes processing its last request. • Manual scaling: accrual ends fifteen minutes after an instance shuts down. If the number of idle instances created by App Engine exceeds the maximum you specify in the Performance Settings tab of the Cloud Console, the excess instances do not accrue instance hours.